# Can static_const<size_t>(), std::as_const() or static_cast<const size_t>() be used to declare an array?

Tags: c++, casting, c++17

I tried the three successive lines (each one of them alone) but no one of them worked.
Why??

```
int main()
{
    size_t j{8};


    char arr[static_cast<const size_t>(j)]={'t'};
    char arr[static_const<size_t>(j)]={'t'};
    char arr[std::as_const(j)]={'t'};


    arr[7]='\0';
    std::cout<<arr;


    return 0;
}
```

Comment: @RemyLebeau hence there is no benfit for `as::const` except for preventing any function from changing the value of the variable.

Comment: @anonymous: The benefits of `as_const` have nothing to do with declaring arrays or anything to do with constant expressions.

Comment: `std::as_const` simply returns a `const` reference to a non-const variable.  It doesn't magically make the variable itself `const`

Comment: @RemyLebeau Thanks

Comment: @RemyLebeau why didn't you post your comment as an answer.

Comment: @anonymous I have now

Comment: What’s `static_const`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

None of your 3 examples are **constants at compile-time**, because `j` is **not assigned a value until runtime**. No amount of *casting* `j` will change that.

To assign `j` at compile-time, you need to declare it as `const` (or `constexpr` in C++11 and later) and then you can use `j` as-is for declaring the array:

```cpp
int main()
{
    const size_t j{8};
    // or: constexpr size_t j{8};

    char arr[j]={'t'};

    arr[7]='\0';
    std::cout<<arr;

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, let's look at an updated bit of code - that actually compiles:

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    constexpr size_t j{8};

    char arr[j]={'t'};

    arr[7]='\0';
    std::cout<<arr;

    return 0;
}
```

`j` is now a compile-time constant, suitable for using to size a built-in array.

Comment: This doesn't answer my question. The answer has given by @RemyLebeau as a comment but he didn't post it. This doesn't convert from nonconstant to constant var

Comment: @anonymous I have posted an answer now

Comment: The answer to the OP's question is: "No. `static_const<size_t>()`, `std::as_const()` or `static_cast<const size_t>()` cannot be used to declare an array".